# How can I prevent redirecting to php file after submission?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a problem with the submission of a form. The form data is sent to the server as it should do but after clicking on the send button I get redirected to the php file. After the submission I would like to keep being on the same page.

Here's the code:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#send").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'submitmessage.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function() {
          console.log("Submission succeeded");
          document.getElementById("send").innerHTML = "Sent";
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("Error");
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="submitmessage.php" method="POST">
  <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" ></input>
  <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" type="email" ></input>
  <textarea id="message" name="message" maxlength="100" placeholder="Write here"></textarea><br>
  <button id="send" name="send">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It is not a redirect but `action="submitmessage.php"`

Comment: The common reason for this is that there's an error elsewhere in your JS code and it breaks the rest of the code, including `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: if you are using ajax you don't need to use the `<form>` tag,  with `action` and `method` , like that you are calling the php file 2 times

Comment: I checked the syntax and it's correct. I tried eliminating action and method but it still won't work. This time it won't even send data to the server.

Comment: You can see right here in the stack snippet that the code (fixed slightly by me) works in general. Do basic debugging in your own script by checking the console and adding `console.log("code got here")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a handler on a specific button, assign it to the Form:

```js
$('form[action="submitmessage.php"]').on("submit", function(e) {

  // prevent default browser form submit 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  
  // We'll use AJAX instead:
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: this.action,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function() {
      $("#send").text("Sent");
    },
    error: function() {
      $("#send").text("Error");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the button `<button id="send" name="send">Submit</button>`. This is a "random" button and the `e.preventDefault();` prevents nothing. If you change it to `<input type="submit" id="send" name="submit" />` now actually submits the form. To prevent this, listen for `$('form').submit(function(e) {});` instead.